# Flutter. Column mainAxisAlignment spaceBetween not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget, flutter-column

I need to position the widgets at the top and bottom, as in this picture.

[image]

For this I am using the following structure:

```
    Column(
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
       children:[
         Column(
            children:[Container(), Container()] // top widgets
               ),
         Container() // bottom widget

             ])
```

But this does not work, my widgets are located strictly one under the other. See also image: [image]

I tried to wrap the outer Column with an Expanded widget, but then I get this error:

> RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints
> are unbounded.
>
> When a row is in a parent that does not provide a finite width
> constraint, for example if it is in a horizontal scrollable, it will
> try to shrink-wrap its children along the horizontal axis. Setting a
> flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to
> expand to fill the remaining space in the horizontal direction. These
> two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap
> its child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.
>
> Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using
> FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible children (using Flexible rather
> than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size
> themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would
> otherwise be forced to take, and then will cause the RenderFlex to
> shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum
> constraints provided by the parent.

I also tried adding mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max for the Column but it didn't help.

P.S. my outer Column is inside the Row, maybe this is the problem?

My full structure:

```
Card(
 child:Padding(
   ...,
   child:Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(... ),
              const SizedBox(width: 4),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: const [
                      Text(...),
                      Text(...),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Container(...)
                ],
              )
            ],
          )
```

The final screen I'm trying to get looks like this:
[image]

Please help me

Comment: I added the `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max` property in the first column.

Comment: check the latest update; what you exactly want

Answer (score 3):

Just use `spacer()` between two `Column` and you can use flex in `Row`

```
Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 4,),
          Expanded(
            flex: 4,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(children: [
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.green,
                          height: 50,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          height: 50,
                        ),
                      ], // top widgets
                    ),
                    Spacer(),
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.brown,
                      height: 50,
                    ) // bottom widget
                  ]),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 4,),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.brown,
                    height: 50,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
```

output:

[image]

Comment: When I add Spacer I get error: RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

Comment: just wrap `Column` with `Expanded` and It will be easy to understand if you will add full code

Comment: check out the dartpad https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?id=b8cbc2af98ed304dcb13e6bf39e00d26

Comment: I have updated my question with the full code structure

Comment: please check out my updated answer and I hope it would be helpful for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

test this example

```
Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
      Expanded(
        flex: 3,
        child: Column(children: [
          Container(height: 100, color: Colors.green),
          Container(height: 100, color: Colors.red)
        ] // top widgets
            ),
      ),
      Container(height: 100, color: Colors.red) // bottom widget
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go !

```
          Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: [
            Expanded(child: containerWithBorder),
            Expanded(
                child: Column(
              children: [
                containerWithBorder,
                containerWithBorder,
                Spacer(),
                containerWithBorder,
              ],
            )),
            Expanded(
                child: Column(
              children: [
                containerWithBorder,
                Spacer(),
              ],
            ))
          ]),
```

[image: image from imulator]

Answer (score 0):

you have to crop that column with container or sizebox

```
SizedBox(
                  height: 250,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          const Text('Country'),

                          const Text('Country'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
```